# How do I fix (TypeError: must be a real number, not a tuple) error?

Tags: python-3.x

**How to solve (TypeError: must be a real number, not a tuple) error**

```
class Vehicle:
    name = ""
    kind = "car"
    color = ""
    value = 100.00
    def description(self):
        desc_str = "%s is a %s %s worth $%.2f." % (self.name, self.color, self.kind, self.value)
        return desc_str

car1 = Vehicle()
car1.name = "Fer"
car1.color = "Red"
car1.kind = "Convertible"
car1.value = 60,000.00

car2 = Vehicle()
car2.name = "Jump"
car2.color = "Blue"
car2.kind = "Van"
car2.value = 10,000.00

print(car1.description())
print(car2.description())
```

After running this code, I'm getting the error. I wanted the info of the cars.

Comment: If you want to separate your numbers to some digit groups you can use `_` in your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For numeric data to be dumped in a variable, Python accepts integer and float only without the use of ',' in between.
A ',' changes the type of the input to a tuple which means,

```
car1.value = 60,000
```

would be stored as (60,0) inside the variable.

Change the value of the below variables to,

```
car1.value = 60000

car2.value = 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written `60,000.00` for the value of your `car1.value` variable. In python a comma is used to separate parameters. You can't use it like you do when hand-writing numbers.

Having a comma there tells python that you have two parameters in the variable: `60` and `000.00`. If you remove the comma, it becomes one parameter. `car1.value` will then store `60000.00`